# Set the webclient hostname in openerp 6.1 all in one Win7 installation

Tags: installation, webclient, config, odoo

System:
Win7 Home,
Open ERP 6.1 all in one

How to set the integrated Webclient Hostname from `localhost:8069` to `127.0.0.1:8069` ?
I need to access the machine for development purposes from the internet.

In Version 6.0 I could find the hostname parameter for the webclient in the file `openerp-web.cfg`. 
But in Version 6.1 the webclient is embed in the core and there is no `openerp-web.cfg`.

**openerp-server.conf**

```
[options]
without_demo = False
smtp_port = 25
db_template = template0
db_password = XXXXXX
xmlrpcs = True
xmlrpcs_interface = 
syslog = False
logrotate = True
xmlrpcs_port = 8071
test_report_directory = False
list_db = True
timezone = False
xmlrpc_interface = 
test_file = False
cache_timeout = 100000
smtp_password = False
secure_pkey_file = server.pkey
xmlrpc_port = 8069
log_level = info
xmlrpc = True
test_disable = False
admin_passwd = XXXXX
assert_exit_level = error
smtp_server = localhost
static_http_url_prefix = None
unaccent = False
test_commit = False
proxy_mode = False
demo = {}
db_host = localhost
login_message = False
import_partial = 
pidfile = False
db_maxconn = 64
osv_memory_count_limit = False
reportgz = False
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0
netrpc_port = 8070
db_port = 5432
virtual_memory_reset = 671088640
db_name = False
debug_mode = False
netrpc = True
secure_cert_file = server.cert
logfile = C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.1-1\server\openerp-server.log
csv_internal_sep = ,
virtual_memory_limit = 805306368
pg_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.1-1\PostgreSQL\bin
static_http_enable = False
cpu_time_limit = 60
translate_modules = ['all']
smtp_ssl = False
server_wide_modules = None
netrpc_interface = 
smtp_user = False
log_handler = [':INFO']
db_user = XXXXX
dbfilter = .*
max_cron_threads = 4
email_from = False
addons_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.1-1\server\openerp\addons
static_http_document_root = None
```

Comment: The "Webclient Hostname" is the machines's hostname. "127.0.0.1" is the same as "localhost" and won't work forem other machine in the network... Can you provide more details on how you are planning to connect from the Internet?

Comment: I have no option in the config file to **set or change the hostname**. At the moment the machine only listen on localhost.
**In older** versions i could configure the hostname in the webclient. But in this version, WebClient and Server running twice and i couldn't find a solution to change the hostname resp. the IP to listen on.

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlrpc_interface = my_ip
xmlrpc_port = my_port
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to change anything on openerp :

1- create a dyndns account ( i use no-ip.com) ,if ur router is configurable to use dynamic dns then ok,else u need to install a client for that on the machine that hosts openerp.

once is that done, u can connect to http://xxx.np-ip.org:8069